# Android encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption

I've been trying to incorporate string encryption into my app and I have a class called Encrypt:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

public class Encrypt {

private String charsetName = "UTF8";
private String algorithm = "DES";
private int base64Mode = Base64.DEFAULT;

public String getCharsetName() {
    return charsetName;
}

public void setCharsetName(String charsetName) {
    this.charsetName = charsetName;
}

public String getAlgorithm() {
    return algorithm;
}

public void setAlgorithm(String algorithm) {
    this.algorithm = algorithm;
}

public int getBase64Mode() {
    return base64Mode;
}

public void setBase64Mode(int base64Mode) {
    this.base64Mode = base64Mode;
}

public String encrypt(String key, String data) {
    if (key == null || data == null)
        return null;
    try {
        Log.d("encrypt: ", "notnull");
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(charsetName));
        Log.d("encrypt", "1");
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        Log.d("encrypt", "2");
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
        Log.d("encrypt", "3");
        byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(charsetName);
        Log.d("encrypt", "4");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        Log.d("encrypt", "5");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        Log.d("encrypt", "6");
        return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(dataBytes), base64Mode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public String decrypt(String key, String data) {
    if (key == null || data == null)
        return null;
    try {
        byte[] dataBytes = Base64.decode(data, base64Mode);
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(charsetName));
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] dataBytesDecrypted = (cipher.doFinal(dataBytes));
        return new String(dataBytesDecrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run it the value returned (from 'encrypt') is null unless I change the charsetName to UTF16BE which seems odd. I logged all the lines to see where specifically the error is happening and it seems as though the program doesn't even get passed the first line of 'encrypt' so:

```
DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(charsetName));
```

Am I using the wrong charset here? when I use the UTF16BE I get results such as:

```
��t��e��s��t
```

anyone know why?

Comment: Why are you silently swallowing exceptions? You'll never figure out what's wrong if you discard and ignore exceptions.

Comment: @GregS when I call e.printStackTrace(); in the catch exception it doesn't print anything

Comment: and neither does Log.e("Exception: ", "exception is: ", e);

Comment: what is your min and target api, and what is the api that you are getting this issue?

Comment: Implementing encryption/decryption correctly in Java can get really complicated with all key generation, encoding, and supporting different datatypes. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/) library.